# Use of "shan't" in speech

Tags: verbs, contractions, spoken-english

Let's assume that someone says, "I shall do this" to me. As a response or a teasing way,
Can I use, *"You shan't..!"* ?

Well, I used this once - when a friend of mine replied: "Huh?" Is it OK to use "shan't" in speech?

I don't think it's only declared for writing purpose. But, are we using this (in speech)..?

Comment: What have you ever come across in writing that you could not say in speech?

Comment: @CarSmack: Pardon me, I didn't mean that I couldn't say in speech. I haven't heard anyone using "shan't" in their speech. I was just curious about that :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Present-day US English you may go for years—I mean that quite literally—without hearing *shan’t*. The only people likely to say it are those with a taste for pre-WWII British literature who have picked it up from their reading.

Note, though, that you may also go for years without hearing anybody say *I shall*. This use was already defunct when I was a child in the 1950s, despite the efforts of schoolteachers to require *shall* in place of *will* in the first person. Today *shall* is reserved, even in formal writing, for

1. pronouncements of a legal or quasi-legal character; it no longer signifies ordinary prediction of the future, but future requirement:

   > The party of the first part **shall** make an accounting quarterly to the party of the second part.
2. rhetorical assertion of unshakeable determination:

   > They shall not pass.
   >   I shall return.
3. *ADDED at Peter Shor's suggestion*: It's sometimes used in first-person questions as a polite suggestion: *Shall we go?* or *Shall we postpone that til we know more?*

So if your interlocutors employ *shall*, they have no cause for complaint if you call them out by responding with *shan’t*; and if they are puzzled, it will give you an opportunity to demonstrate your superior mastery of the English tongue by explaining, condescendingly, what I have set forth above.

Comment: People also sometimes use *shall* for first-person questions, at least in some areas of the country. "Shall we go?" and "Will we go?" mean quite different things, the first being a suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

It’s still used in British English, but perhaps only by an older generation. A typical example might be *I’m just going out. I shan’t be long.*

Of *shall* itself, ‘The Cambridge Guide to English Usage’ says

> **Shall** is stylistically marked with volitional meaning in legal and regulatory statements, and expresses politeness in first person
>   questions.